# Is there a way to access an internal parameter in a custom constructor from struct in Go?

Tags: go, oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I would like to access an internal property in a custom constructor, in my case it's a property from a superclass, like this:

```
type BaseRepository struct {
    database mongo.Database
}

type PointRepository struct {
    BaseRepository

    pointCollection mongo.Collection
}

func NewPointRepository() *PointRepository {
    pointCollection := ***self***.database.GetCollection("points")

    pr := &PointRepository{
        pointCollection: pointpointCollection,
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to access something like **self** to this approach works.

How can I workaround this situation?

Comment: Best advice: don't copy patterns from OO languages in Go, it will not end well. With that said, if you want to access the `database` field from the same `BaseRepository` instance that will be set into `PointRepository`, you can pass a `BaseRepository` as argument to the constructor

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm just afraid if this would be a "testable" code since I want to mock the database.

Comment: `mongo.Database` is a struct, not an interface. How are you planning to mock it?

Comment: @BurakSerdar, is it a big impeditive?

Comment: Go doesn't have constructors, classes, superclasses, subclasses, internal fields, or really anything you'd find in an object-oriented language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

> Add `Set` function for `BaseRepository`

Solution 2:

> use `unsafe` package

```
type BaseRepository struct {
    database string
}

type PointRepository struct {
    BaseRepository
    pointCollection string
}
```

---

```
baseRepository := &internel.BaseRepository{}
databasePointer := (*string)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(baseRepository))))
*databasePointer = "changed here"
fmt.Printf("%+v",baseRepository)
```

---

output:

```
&{database:changed here}
```

**This is just an example, you should change the type of the field database.**

Answer (score 2):

There are no constructors or classes in Go.

`PointRepository` embeds `BaseRepository`, which has an unexported `database` field. Any function in the same package as `BaseRepository` can directly access the `database` field.

If you need to access that field from a function outside the package, you either have to export it, or you have to provide an exported getter method in `BaseRepository`.

Comment: In this case they are under the same repository, so a getter method would be the best option I think.

Comment: It doesn't matter where `PointRepository` is defined. It matters where you need to access the `database` field. If the func that accesses the `database` field in the same package as the `BaseRepository` you can directly access it. In you code, the `NewPointRepository` function should either get a `database` argument, or a `BaseRepository` argument.

Comment: I see, like a normal dependency. Thanks so much for the help.